# in Karate DSL, is there a way to have redirects perform a POST request instead of a GET request?

Tags: karate, http-status-code-302

I have the following Karate script that by default has redirects turned on.

```
  Scenario: First Test
    Given path 'somePath'
    And request ''
    And header Content-Type = 'text/html'
    And param _csrf = csrf
    And param username = 'username'
    And param password = 'password'
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

The issue is after getting a 302 from the API, the next request automatically submits a GET request. I would like it to submit a POST request instead.

in cURL, there is an existing parameter that allows users to do that. see below.

--post302       Do not switch to GET after following a 302

is there anyway to do that in Karate DSL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes please read the docs for [`configure folowRedirects`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure). There is also an example on how to read the `Location` response header to manually make the request you want.

```
Scenario: get redirects can be disabled
* configure followRedirects = false
Given path 'redirect'
When method get
Then status 302
And match header Location == demoBaseUrl + '/search'
* def location = responseHeaders['Location'][0]
Given url location
```

Comment: I should have given more details on the initial question but I am not trying to manually redirect the requests. I simply want each redirected request to automatically retry with a POST request instead of a GET request. is this possible? I want to avoid turning off followRedirects because redirection can happen multiple times with the service I am working with.

Comment: I went back and accepted the answer to previous questions. I'm still stuck on This one though. Any thoughts on how to Auto POST when redirects are on?

Comment: @Lincoln88 I honestly don't know why the apache client doesn't use a POST for the re-direct. here is more context: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/216 - just manually do the second request and you can switch back to follow-redirects later. else please submit a pull request ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since multiple redirects can happen with the service I'm working with, it can end up being a long ugly script if I manually redirect. I created the request here. https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/668

Comment: for the benefit of others who come across this - if there is a need for this pattern in multiple calls in your flows (extremely rare) you can easily write a re-usable feature file to do the work of extracting the `Location` from the previous request, re-playing the request body with the method of your choice and re-setting the `followRedirects` flag if necessary.